# Use Application Load Balancer (ALB) to trigger Lambda functions, how to add a bit of authentication at the ALB level?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have a React app which calls API gateway, which in turn triggers my Lambda functions. Now for saving cost purpose due to the potentially let’s say, tens of millions of requests to the API gateway, I did some research and are looking at to potentially use ALB to invoke my Lambdas rather than API GW. My API GW is simply a Lambda-Proxy integration.

My question is with API GW I can add API keys and custom authorizers etc, but for ALB, how do I add a bit of authentication at the ALB layer, say only allow the invocation of my Lambda functions only from the client that I trust? Note my client is a static React app with no server behind it! I don’t need anything too fancy but just want to reject requests other than my trusted request origins. Inside Lambda to cover browser I will just add CORS to response header. But at ALB level, how do I achieve what I required?

Looking forward to getting some shed of lights here!

Thanks

Comment: I don't think ALB will be a cost effective option for the described use case. There are quite a few ways you can implement authentication at API Gateway. So `only allow the invocation of my Lambda functions only from the client that I trust` how do you want to identify the client? User making request to your API endpoint are authenticated? If so, how do you authenticate users?

Comment: At the moment, I only used api keys but my routes are only get routes which only expose public available data so it is not really a problem there. However I'm thinking this in a broader context, if at some point I need to add some post routes that will allow the caller to update the data, using api gateway I can add custom authn/z. As for ALB, how would I achieve that? Is it enough to just use the condition of host and path at the ALB settings? To be honest my only concern about api gateway is the cost, if the traffic goes wild, it will be a lot of money isn't it?

Comment: API Gateway appears to be the most cost effective option for your use case. You only pay what you use unlike configuring an ALB. Your concern about traffic/cost can be addressed by configuring throttling on your API according to your requirement. API Gateway-throttled requests are not charged when the request rate or burst rate exceeds the preconfigured limits. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-pricing.html

Comment: So the reason I'm raising the question is I found this -https://serverless-training.com/articles/save-money-by-replacing-api-gateway-with-application-load-balancer/ , in my case, what if my legitimate traffic volume is indeed huge? I can understand if I put a throttle limit there but that is for attacks, isn't it? What if I do have a large number of requests to serve? It looks like in that scenario it might be worthwhile to use an ALB to trigger Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Is it an option using AWS Cognito or CloudFront? We did that with an Enterprise application which uses OIDC (OAuth 2.0). It does implement just Authentication for now.

Give a look in these links:
https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws/built-in-authentication-in-alb/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html